# Get rid of comment timer for question asker

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting

This is only a tiny request!

I just asked a question on Stack Overflow and got three answers. I marked one of them as answer and just out of politeness I wanted to both up-vote and leave a comment for them all saying "+1 - Thanks for the help", or similar.

15 seconds really is not a lot and I can easily wait, but can this be lifted for the question asker in their own question as I have run against this a few times and there surely must be others? ... If I had 5 or more answers, I can imagine it becoming annoying!

Comment: See also: [Please make the multiple comment timer less annoying (non-resetting etc.)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164048)

Answer (score 5):

You should be carefully crafting your comments, not just indiscriminately tossing out the same copy-pasted reply. We don't want to encourage people tossing out comments rapidly, even on their own question sequences.

The upvote alone (and acceptance when that comes in) is already indication of your thanks - use a comment to explain why that specific answer was actually helpful. Barring those fast typists, the time spent formulating the specific comments and then typing them out will be more than enough time to get past 15 seconds.

If multiple answers were helpful in the exact same degree or if you find you're going to make the exact same comment, then you only need to make one comment that addresses everyone. When these turn up for myself, I tend to put these on either the answer I do accept, or on my question.

Comment: I understand fully what you are saying, especially the last part. I understand what you mean about leaving a comment on the question, but I do not think many people check that after they have written an answer. I know for a fact that when I leave an answer on Super User, I really like it when someone says "Thank you" or similar, even if they marked someone else's as an answer - as far as I am concerned, it is just polite / showing appreciation.... I would agree with you if it was possible to write a comment on a question something like "@all - Many thanks" & have it alert users.