# Please make the multiple comment timer less annoying (non-resetting etc.)

Tags: feature-request, comments, rate-limiting, spam-detection

As a little feature to prevent comment spam, you can only enter one comment every 15 seconds. That's a very reasonable limitation, since you very rarely have a good reason to write comments that quickly. I've only seen it twice at all, I think, but both times it was **extremely annoying**.

> Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset.

The reason is that every time you hit the limit, the 15 seconds begin anew. You have no indicator that tells you when you are allowed to comment again, and if you hit enter after just 14 seconds, you're back to zero. Yesterday, I went through four cycles of not quite 15 seconds, counting in my head, before I got a myself a coffee and tried again afterwards.

I suggest that you do one or more of the following (in decreasing order):

- Make the counter non-restarting
- Add a visible countdown
- Make it clearly visible that you can't comment right now
- You can actually *increase* the waiting time, if it is clearly visible and there is no unnerving invisible countdown. Actually, just remove all comment fields after one comment, and tell the user to reload the page. Just *please* don't have UI elements that look like they would work, but feel like they are trolling you.

Comment: The timer reset will prevent a scripted loop to do any harm.

Comment: Agreed, but there's practically zero chance it will be fixed. They won't do anything about [a similar but even more annoying misfeature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote), no way they'll do anything to this one either.

Comment: A scripted loop is better at measuring time intervals than a human being. It will comment spam with the greatest of ease.

Comment: I never had this problem on the mobile version.

Comment: Possible fix: change the message to say "Only 1 attempt to comment allowed per 15 seconds, whether successful or not; timer reset." Now at least the message accurately describes the situation!

Comment: I propose a MMO-like visible cooldown for the `Add Comment`-"skill"

Comment: It seems everyone agrees that this is *really* annoying and yet nothing been done so far. And even more annoying is the lack of response from SO team. I don't think this can possibly be justified by anyone. [This is NOT just a new request. It's been asked two years ago.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64854/comment-timer-resets-on-invalid-comment). And they say "for the community by the community..".

Comment: Man, bounties are *&@$ _useless_ on Meta. I've lost 100 rep and have to award it now to ... someone. Despite the fact that nothing new has been done on this feature request. Sigh.

Comment: This is the SO version of [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/) ([pointless, repetitive clicking..](http://i.imgur.com/WUjQQbU.png))

Comment: Here is [the guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) to rate limiting.

Comment: This feels like a lingering Jeff-ism.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In _another_ life I gave away a _lot_ of bounties. I learned that they're a blunt instrument for getting attention. They say "someone, anyone, post something", and rarely get the attention of the people you really want. I switched to using them almost exclusively to reward existing answers on inherently interesting topics. This was ironically much more effective at getting the attention of the very users I was previously hoping to attract to unanswered questions.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery: There is next to no comment spam on SO and rate limiting has nothing to do with that. It has to do with the reputation barrier. Your blog doesn't appear to be a relevant datapoint.

Comment: I think the solution to this problem is an autoflag for potentially abusive commenting, not a resetting timer. Keep the rate limit at 15 seconds, and have Community ♦ raise a flag if a user posts more than, say, 12 comments in 5 minutes.

Comment: @DragonLordtheFiery Because moderators don't get enough  comment flags? SE is looking hard for ways to reduce the comment-flag workload, not to increase it.

Comment: Not an [so] regular, so I'm not at all familiar with these issues. I'm mostly on Super User, which has far less volume.

Comment: I haven't encountered this problem in a long time. I presume it was fixed.

Answer (score 65):

[Comment (and comment-voting) rate-limiting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=comment+rate+limiting+is%3Aquestion) is one of the most irritating features on these sites and there are many requests to fix it, [here's one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35501/please-return-the-comment-rate-limit-to-a-flat-30-seconds).

Not everyone can time 15-seconds in their head well, and the big irritant is that once you get the message the timer reboots itself.  So you get to sit there trying to time it again; **it's like a game, but not a fun one.**

EDIT: The comment voting rate limit has been eliminated, as per [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331/13295).

Comment: Everybody says this. I don't experience it. Just tested on the comments on Lightness' answer. Vote on comment 1. Wait four seconds. Vote on comment 2: "wait a bit". Wait one second. Vote on comment 2, it takes. Might be a reputation thing, I should dig through Meta for references.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, it would be nice to know if they changed it.  I occasionally get it, but not like I used to.

Comment: They did removed the rate limit to comment voting.

Comment: @Braiam, do you have a reference for that?

Comment: There you go [Can we get x comment votes per y minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331)

Comment: @Braiam, thanks.  I've edited the rate-limit guide.

Answer (score 41):

Oh yes this is **incredibly annoying**!

There cannot be a reasonable argument for the auto-reset. I type and think quickly, and I multi-task. What begins as a reasonably quick comment job on a few answers on the same question (or even on different question on different tabs) becomes an arduous cat-and-mouse game with the SO interface.

And why? Because the interface wants me to "take more care and attention"? Thanks but I'll be the judge of that. This just hinders my workflow.

Answer (score 34):

Quoting points 2 and 3 from your suggestions:

> - Add a visible countdown
> - Make it clearly visible that you can't    comment right now

Addressing those, here is a userscript that does three things:

- adds a timer to the error message
- disables the comment form submit button for the duration of the timeout
- lets you know when it is safe to comment (error message changes)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It would be nice if we could get something like this for all the timeout errors we have on the site.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Comment Timer
// @namespace   http://example.com
// @include     http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, options) {
    if(xhr.status == 409 && xhr.responseText == "Only 1 comment allowed per 15 seconds; timer reset."){
        var span = $('<span class="timer">15</span>'),
            interval;
        $('.error-message').append(" Time remaining: ", span);
        function callback(){
            var time = ~~$(this).text();
            if(--time>0){
                $(this).text(time).delay(1000).queue(callback).dequeue();
            }else{
                $(this).parent().text("You may submit your comment now.");
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }
        span.delay(1000).queue(callback);
        $('.comment-form input[type="submit"]').stop(true, true).prop('disabled', true).animate({dummy:1},15000).queue(function(){
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why disable input? So I can't type the comment while I wait? Disable the "Add Comment" button

Comment: @CodesInChaos Good point. Updated.

Comment: It would be nice to have this script published on http://userscripts.com (easier to install, auto-updates, easier to find when you're on a lended computer)

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not planning on maintaining this and don't have an account on that site, but you're welcome to publish this there if you think it would be useful. I might update this to cover other timers (vote count fetching, comment votes) although those are non-resetting, so it isn't as big a deal.

Comment: Too bad Chrome doesn't allow arbitrary userscripts that aren't in the web store, any more :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not directly, but   dropping the file at `chrome://extensions/` page used to work recently. Have they disabled that too?

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: Yes that is exactly what they have disabled (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24095006/560648)

Answer (score 12):

FTR, I have never changed my mind about a comment based on the timer being reset.  I think the reason the timer was reset was to *prevent users from pressing ENTER ENTER ENTER ENTER* until the comment went through.

Was there a serious technical reason for needing to stop users from banging their keyboards?  Or was it just "HEY! STOP BANGING YOUR KEYBOARD! THAT'S IT. YOU'RE WAITING LONGER NOW."

Another thing you could do to ease tension is show a **little** clock icon, about the size of the edit pencil.  The clock fills up with black or red and when it is completely full, wait time is up.

Comment: You know, I think you're right. I'd never thought about it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough JavaScript to attempt implementing this idea myself, or even to know if it is realistically possible, but as a work-around how about a userscript that enables you to enter multiple comments quickly, but buffers them and submits them to the system at 20 second intervals.

Answer (score 0):

#### Replace the timer reset with an automatic flag for too many comments in too short a period of time.

- The resetting timer is an annoyance. Yes, Jeff is right when he said that [we must design for abuse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/designing-for-evil.html). However, Jeff has tended to prefer strong automated solutions, even where it interferes with the user experience, because they avoid burdening moderators. Comment abuse is rare, so I don't believe this is an issue. As much as we want to avoid overburdening our "human exception handlers", there is often no substitute for human intervention.
- Instead of resetting the timer on trying to post more than one comment per 15 seconds, have Community ♦ raise a flag on the last comment posted if some user posts more than, say, 12 comments in 5 minutes. That way, if someone or something does decide to abuse the commenting feature, it can be taken care of effectively.
- The rate limit itself should stand at 15 seconds per comment.

Comment: How will it combat abuse when they've already gone and posted the comments? There is already a flag when there are too many comments on the whole, which would already cover when one or more users get comment chatty. Do not want to deal with yet another flag that will only be followed up by the existing flag behaviour.

Answer (score -8):

Patience, padawan.

There are reasons this system is in place that go beyond spam protection. By forcing users to pause for fifteen seconds, they do just that: pause. If someone's posting an angry comment, they pause. It eases frustration and forces users to think for more than three seconds about what they're posting.

Of course it's a spam protection filter, but it also prevents careless comments. It also prompts, for thoughtful users, that they should instead edit their previous comment (when applicable).

And for those few users who can generate two well-thought-out comments in a span of fifteen seconds: patience. You do yourself no good obsessing over wasted seconds.

Edit: To clarify, I'm not saying I enjoy waiting, nor that my time is valueless. What I'm saying is that I do not let a fifteen second pause in my day frustrate me, much in the same way that being cut off does not frustrate me. I do my best to be patient with delays, and to stop the little things like this from bothering me. You don't have to agree with me. Still, I prefer the calm of patience to the stress of meticulous temporal preservation.

Comment: Sure, but when you've accidentally waited 14 seconds and submitted, to be made to wait **another 15 seconds** - which you may still guess wrong about - is crazy-making

Comment: @KateGregory There's this new-fangled invention that measures time. I think they call it clog or something similar. No need to guess anymore.

Comment: The thing is, we talk about "frustration", but the problem is not that we don't have patience or time. The problem is that the present solution is a bad user interface design. The comment box looks active, but it is not, and in fact the user gets "punished" for using it. As the instintual animals that humans are, one might even feel like the site is "acting up" against one. What makes it worse is that this site has an otherwise excellent user interface, and it's makers usually make the right decisions regarding the subtleties of human-computer interaction.

Comment: @DanielFischer if I have to start an external timer so I can see if it's 14 seconds or 15 seconds yet, how happy am I with that UI? I find it especially spiteful that it RESTARTS after I misguess. I see no good reason for that at all. It's just a mean joke.

Comment: I do not subscribe to the "don't fix poor interfaces — be zen and put up with it" mentality on a website dedicated to reporting problems with the interface.

Comment: The feature makes me more angry, not less.